# A variant of Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra

I found this algorithm from CP3 book for ICPC, it is a variant of Dijkstra but it gives TLE in some cases (hidden tests). Although it seems that the running time of this algorithm is same as Dijkstra but I think it is different. Can anyone help me with the time complexity of this algorithm.

```
 vector<int> visited(N,0),dis(N,0);
 vector<pair<int,int> > adj[N];        // value, node
 void dijkstra()                    
 {
     for(int i=2;i<=N;i++)
        dis[i]=N;
     priority_queue<pair<int,int> ,vector<pair<int,int> >,greater<pair<int,int> > > pq;
     pq.push(make_pair(0,1));
     while(!pq.empty())
     {
         pair<int,int> p=pq.top();
         ll x=p.second;
         pq.pop();
         if(p.first>dis[x])
             continue;
         for(int i=0;i<adj[x].size();i++)
         {
             if(dis[adj[x][i].ss]>dis[x]+adj[x][i].first)
             {
                 dis[adj[x][i].second]=dis[x]+adj[x][i].first;
                 pq.push(make_pair(dis[adj[x][i].second],adj[x][i].second));
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: .ff is the first value of pair and .ss is to access the second value.

Comment: The pair stores `<weight, connecting node>` for a particular edge

Comment: Sorry for that, it was by mistake. I corrected it

Comment: Actually I've written it myself, but didn't posted the whole code as it would be difficult to read

Comment: Then stop #defining new, non-descriptive names for things that everyone already knows. 
 Anyway... you're using dis[N], but it only has indexes up to N-1.  Probably visited too. Those are buffer overruns.  Also, `dis[i]=N` is not necessarily a high enough value.  In C++ you should start counting at 0

Comment: Anyway, when the bugs are fixed, this algorithm takes O(|V|+|E| log |V|) time.

Comment: Why assigning `dis[i] = N`? And also make sure there is no negative weight.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ are zero based, that is the first index is 0 and the last is size()-1.

```
 vector<int> visited(N,0),dis(N,0); <--- dis is initialized with N zero's
 vector<pair<int,int> > adj[N];        // value, node
 void dijkstra()                    
 {
     for(int i=2;i<=N;i++)
        dis[i]=N; <---- initializing i=N or dis[N] is undefined behaviour
```

You write beyond the end of the array with possible disastrous results.
Your real error might be that that

```
dis[1] = 0
```

Where it should have been N or MAX_INT.

Answer (score -1):

This algorithm can run infinitely when there exists a graph of a particular pattern. `p.first>dis[x]` may not always be `true` and then it will not exit the loop.

I believe that is the only part which is changed from the original Dijkstra algorithm

Comment: This didn't helped me at all

Comment: A push only happens in the loop, if a `dis` element is decreased. Assuming non-negative edge weights per vertex this can only happen up to `N` times for each vertex, so regardless of the exact complexity the algorithm will eventually terminate assuming non-negative edge weights.